# Appending dictionaries to list overrides all dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary let's say `my_dic` and I want to append it to a list through a loop modifying the value of `my_dic`, here is the example and it works by the way:

```
my_lst = []
my_dic = {
    'hello': 'World'
}
my_lst.append(my_dic)
my_dic = {
    'hello': 'World 2'
}
my_lst.append(my_dic)
```

and it returns `[{'hello': 'World'}, {'hello': 'World 2'}]` which is what I want and it works correctly. But there is another place where the same thing doesn't work.

```
query = """
           SELET * FROM some_table
        """

connection = mysql.connector.connect(user=user, 
                                                password=password,
                                                host=host,
                                                database=database)
cursor = connection.cursor(dictionary=True)
cursor.execute(query)   

rows=cursor.fetchall()


data= []
tempRow = rows[0]

tempRow['RS'] = 'old value'
data.append(tempRow)

tempRow = rows[0]
tempRow['RS'] = '1'
data.append(tempRow)


pp(data)
```

which returns `data` like this:

```
[{'RS': '1'}, {'RS': '1'}]
```

however, I expect it like this:

```
[{'RS': 'old value'}, {'RS': '1'}]
```

Edited: I have removed the loop.

Comment: You are creating a new list *each loop iteration*. If you expected a single list with all loop iteration results appended, you would want to create the list *once*, before looping.

Comment: When you assign `tempRow = rows[0]`, that doesn't make a copy of the dict in `rows[0]`. When you modify `tempRow`, you modify `rows[0]` as well. Use `tempRow = rows[0].copy()` instead.

Comment: @Aran-Fey you are right. How do I make a copy?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Forget about the loop, I have removed that in the question too and tested without loop as well, no luck!

Comment: @Aran-Fey you are right. tempRow = rows[0].copy() , got it, thanks. It worked!